# Fullcalendar showing all events under plus events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I don't know whether it is a bug or some misconfiguration at my end, my fullcalendar shows all events in popup and not a single event in the box. And this is happening inconsistently like not for all the events.

[image]

I tried to put this limit but this does not work for me:

```
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
events: '../../../../fullcale.ashx',
editable: true,
droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events            
views: {
    agenda: {
        eventLimit: 2 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
    }
},
```

Comment: `views: {
    agenda: {
        eventLimit: 2 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
    }
},` will only affect "agenda" style views, whereas your screenshot is showing a "month" view.

Comment: As for `eventLimit: true`...read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimit - " value of true will limit the number of events to the height of the day cell". But the behaviour above seems odd and not per spec. Can you create a JSFiddle or CodePen which reproduces the issue, please? I cannot immediately reproduce it. You can modify it from https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001. Perhaps you have an event with a very long description or something, which would cause it to exceed the height of the day cell.

Comment: Yeah, your idea was completely fine, I tried reducing font size by 2 points and it worked.

Comment: Can you make an answer so that I may mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimit says

> "a value of true will limit the number of events to the height of the
>   day cell".

So perhaps you have an event with a very long description or something, which would cause it to exceed the height of the day cell.

To fix it you can do something like setting a specific value for `eventLimit`, or changing your font size, trimming the description to a fixed length, or alternatively you can simply accept that this is the behaviour of the system.